# Why is poetry not recognized in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell, python-poetry

I'm totally new to all of this so kind of not sure what I'm doing. I was following instructions to install some program I found on GitHub(also first time). And this is what I have right now:

```
PS C:\Users\owenw> python --version
Python 3.12.0
PS C:\Users\owenw> poetry --version
No Python at '"D:\python.exe'
```

How can I fix this?

At first even the python wasn't working and then I realized that I had installed python somewhere else in my computer before so I uninstalled everything and now at least the python works. But I don't know if I can "uninstall" poetry to reset this.

Answer (score 2):

The poetry is looking for python at D drive.

Maybe you can resolve this by these steps:

1. To check the Python interpreter configured for Poetry, run

   **poetry config --list**
2. To set it to the correct path use the command

   **poetry config interpreter.path "C:\path\to\your\python.exe"**

   For example: If your python path is located in **C:\Python3120\python.exe**
   then the command should look like **poetry config interpreter.path "C:\Python3120\python.exe"**